# Graph Api FQL missing images in the response

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to query facebook graph api on posts in the user groups.
I'm using FQL and querying stream table on specific group posts.
The response i'm receiving is missing the images, but I can see the pictures in the group itself.
It happens to me only in specific posts.

This is my query:

```
select attachment, post_id from stream where post_id = 'SOME_POST_ID'
```

I managed to detect some pattern, all the images that are hosted by facebook on "sphotos-h.ak.fbcdn.net" domains are missing from the graph api, while the other domains work fine.

I need these missing pictures so my app will work properly.

Thanks!

Comment: This is probably a problem with permissions... Did you try to add the "read_stream" permission?

Comment: Same result, still no photo.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and found that if the posting user has not granted permissions for apps that **others** use to view their photos, then those images will not show through the Graph API.

Take a look at the "Apps Others Use" section under your own app settings.

https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications

They need to have the "My Photos" permission checked.